# Populating the "Details" section in crystal report with multiple rows dynamically

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, crystal-reports, mdf

I've had a crystal report that I am population from a stored procedure, however, when I converted the database to an MDF file for deployment, I couldn't connect to the MDF from the database expert since it's not supported by crystal reports, when I try to fill the report dynamically, it all works fine,  except in the details section where I have multiple rows, it only displays the first one in case I tried to fill the report from a data table, because I wasn't able to **generate rows in "Details" section depending on the number of rows I have in my DataTable**.

Then I tried:

```cs
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
sda.Fill(ds);
//IF is the RPT file
InvoiceFinal IF = new InvoiceFinal();
IF.DataSourceConnections.Clear();
MessageBox.Show(ds.Tables.Count.ToString());
IF.SetDataSource(ds);
Print p = new Print();
p.crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = IF;
```

This method returns this error: **Failed to load database information**

I looked up a solution for the error above but nothing worked.

I would like to know if there is a way to add rows dynamically to section 3 in the report or if there is any fix for the error above, or even if there is another workaround to accomplish my goal.

Comment: MDF file must be physically on a drive that is located on same machine as the SQL Server.  Usually you use c: but if a d: drive is on same machine as the database that will also work.

Comment: @jdweng it is on the same drive as the SQL server, but not directly on the drive it's inside the project folder

Comment: I think there is an issue with a Primary Key on the table you can add only one row.  When you set a Primary Key in DQL Server is allows only one row with the value.  If you old database has more than one row with the same key then you must remove the Primary Key from the column.

Comment: The mdf file can be any folder on the drive as long as the folder is not a link to another machine.

Comment: @jdweng The database works fine, I tried to print the data from the table to check if it's the problem but everything seems okay, the rows I am trying to extract don't contain primary keys as they are returned from a stored procedure

Comment: See following : https://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/BOBJ/Troubleshooting+Issues+with+VS+.NET+Datasets+and+Crystal+Reports